# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException errors

Tags: java

I can't exactly figure out what the issue is. I think it has to do with the array list but I'm not quite sure how to fix this. I've tried to instead of returning the array list, add to a new array list created in the main function but that didn't work. The error I keep getting is:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

```
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)

    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)

    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)

    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)

    at fileAnalyze.inputFileList(fileAnalyze.java:18)

    at fileAnalyze.main(fileAnalyze.java:6)
```

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class fileAnalyze {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Integer> inputFileInfo = inputFileList("inputFile.txt");
        int count = numberAmount(inputFileInfo), small = inputFileInfo.get(argmin(inputFileInfo)),
        big = inputFileInfo.get(argmax(inputFileInfo)), theAverage = average(inputFileInfo);
        
        fileCreate(count, small, big, theAverage);
    }

    private static ArrayList <Integer> inputFileList(String n){
        Scanner reading = new Scanner(n);
        ArrayList<Integer> inputFileData = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            while (reading.hasNextLine()){
            int data = reading.nextInt();
            inputFileData.add(data);
        }
        reading.close();
        return inputFileData;
    }

    private static int numberAmount(ArrayList<Integer> n1){
        return n1.size();

    }
    private static int argmin(ArrayList<Integer> n2){
        int arg= -1, x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n2.size(); i++){
            if (n2.get(i) < x){
                arg = i;
                x = n2.get(i);
            }
        }
        return arg;
    }

    private static int argmax(ArrayList<Integer> n3){
        int arg= -1, x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n3.size(); i++){
            if (n3.get(i) < x){
                arg = i;
                x = n3.get(i);
            }
        }
        return arg;
    }

    private static int average(ArrayList<Integer> n4){
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n4.size(); i++){
            total = total + n4.get(i);
        }
        int average = total / n4.size();
        return average;
    }

    private static void fileCreate(int numberCount, int minNum, int maxNum, int avg){
        try {
            File outputFile = new File("outputFile.txt");
            if (outputFile.createNewFile()) {
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("File already exists");
            }
            FileWriter writing = new FileWriter("outputFile.txt");
            writing.write("**********");
            writing.write("There are " + Integer.toString(numberCount) + " numbers in this file.");
            writing.write("The minimum number is " + Integer.toString(minNum));
            writing.write("The maximum number is " + Integer.toString(maxNum));
            writing.write("The average is " + Integer.toString(avg));
            writing.close();
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("An error has occured.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is something in your input file that is not an int.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code to

```
while (reading.hasNextLine()){
    String line = reading.nextLine ();
    try{
        Integer data= Integer.valueOf(line);
        inputFileData.add(data);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This will allow you to read your file even if it has blanks lines or other non-integer junk

Comment: I tried to add this and now under the inputFileList() I get this error instead:
inputFileData cannot be resolved or is not a fieldJava(33554502)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

Here : `int data = reading.nextInt();`

You are trying to get an Integer from the file but a file may contain characters and not just integers.

**Solution:**

To make sure you read only integer from the file, you need to catch an expection if the file contains a non desirable input.

Change this line :
`int data = reading.nextInt();`

To:

```
try {
    int data = reading.nextInt();
catch(InputMismatchException e) {
    //Your code for handing exception.
}
```

Comment: *but is the user really entering a integer* The user is not entering anything.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()):

> InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range

So either ensure your input is a legal int value or add the try/catch clause.